# How can I get around memory limitation in this script?

Tags: python

I'm trying to normalize my dataset which is `1.7 Gigabyte`. I have `14Gig of RAM` and I hit my limit very quickly.

This happens when computing the `mean/std` of the training data. The training data takes up the majority of the memory when loaded into `RAM(13.8Gig)`,thus the mean gets calculated, but when it reaches to the next line while calculating the `std`, it crashes.

Follows the script:

```
import caffe
import leveldb
import numpy as np
from caffe.proto import caffe_pb2
import cv2
import sys
import time

direct = 'examples/svhn/'
db_train = leveldb.LevelDB(direct+'svhn_train_leveldb')
db_test = leveldb.LevelDB(direct+'svhn_test_leveldb')
datum = caffe_pb2.Datum()

#using the whole dataset for training which is 604,388
size_train = 604388 #normal training set is 73257
size_test = 26032
data_train = np.zeros((size_train, 3, 32, 32))
label_train = np.zeros(size_train, dtype=int)

print 'Reading training data...'
i = -1
for key, value in db_train.RangeIter():
    i = i + 1
    if i % 1000 == 0:
        print i
    if i == size_train:
        break
    datum.ParseFromString(value)
    label = datum.label
    data = caffe.io.datum_to_array(datum)
    data_train[i] = data
    label_train[i] = label

print 'Computing statistics...'
print 'calculating mean...'
mean = np.mean(data_train, axis=(0,2,3))
print 'calculating std...'
std = np.std(data_train, axis=(0,2,3))

#np.savetxt('mean_svhn.txt', mean)
#np.savetxt('std_svhn.txt', std)

print 'Normalizing training'
for i in range(3):
        print i
        data_train[:, i, :, :] = data_train[:, i, :, :] - mean[i]
        data_train[:, i, :, :] = data_train[:, i, :, :]/std[i]


print 'Outputting training data'
leveldb_file = direct + 'svhn_train_leveldb_normalized'
batch_size = size_train

# create the leveldb file
db = leveldb.LevelDB(leveldb_file)
batch = leveldb.WriteBatch()
datum = caffe_pb2.Datum()

for i in range(size_train):
    if i % 1000 == 0:
        print i

    # save in datum
    datum = caffe.io.array_to_datum(data_train[i], label_train[i])
    keystr = '{:0>5d}'.format(i)
    batch.Put( keystr, datum.SerializeToString() )

    # write batch
    if(i + 1) % batch_size == 0:
        db.Write(batch, sync=True)
        batch = leveldb.WriteBatch()
        print (i + 1)

# write last batch
if (i+1) % batch_size != 0:
    db.Write(batch, sync=True)
    print 'last batch'
    print (i + 1)
#explicitly freeing memory to avoid hitting the limit!
#del data_train
#del label_train

print 'Reading test data...'
data_test = np.zeros((size_test, 3, 32, 32))
label_test = np.zeros(size_test, dtype=int)
i = -1
for key, value in db_test.RangeIter():
    i = i + 1
    if i % 1000 == 0:
        print i
    if i ==size_test:
        break
    datum.ParseFromString(value)
    label = datum.label
    data = caffe.io.datum_to_array(datum)
    data_test[i] = data
    label_test[i] = label

print 'Normalizing test'
for i in range(3):
        print i
        data_test[:, i, :, :] = data_test[:, i, :, :] - mean[i]
        data_test[:, i, :, :] = data_test[:, i, :, :]/std[i]

#Zero Padding
#print 'Padding...'
#npad = ((0,0), (0,0), (4,4), (4,4))
#data_train = np.pad(data_train, pad_width=npad, mode='constant', constant_values=0)
#data_test = np.pad(data_test, pad_width=npad, mode='constant', constant_values=0)

print 'Outputting test data'
leveldb_file = direct + 'svhn_test_leveldb_normalized'
batch_size = size_test

# create the leveldb file
db = leveldb.LevelDB(leveldb_file)
batch = leveldb.WriteBatch()
datum = caffe_pb2.Datum()

for i in range(size_test):
    # save in datum
    datum = caffe.io.array_to_datum(data_test[i], label_test[i])
    keystr = '{:0>5d}'.format(i)
    batch.Put( keystr, datum.SerializeToString() )

    # write batch
    if(i + 1) % batch_size == 0:
        db.Write(batch, sync=True)
        batch = leveldb.WriteBatch()
        print (i + 1)

# write last batch
if (i+1) % batch_size != 0:
    db.Write(batch, sync=True)
    print 'last batch'
    print (i + 1)
```

How can I make it consume less memory so that I can get to run the script?

Comment: The larger the data you are trying to normalize, the more likely you are to run out of memory to run the program; make the data size less

Comment: if that means reducing the training set, that is not possible. I need to normalize the whole set.

Comment: You can read the data as a memory map (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html), or write your own version of mean which sequentially reads one (or multiple) datapoint(s) in the file and computes the `mean`/`std`. The mean is just the sum of all data divided by the length (pseudocode: `sum_i x_i / N`), so you don't need the whole dataset in memory to compute the mean. Same for the standard deviation, you don't need the whole dataset in memory, just compute the mean and calculate `sqrt(sum_i (x_i - x_mean)**2 / (N-1))`.

Comment: @ChristophTerasa: I tried your suggestion, but after deleting the pointer which should save the file onto the disk, it doesnt do anything, I mean, a file does get created, with the size of 14.9 Gigabyte, but the next command does not get executed!
This is the codes regarding our case:

`fp = np.memmap(directory+'train_data_memmap', dtype=data_train.dtype, mode='w+', shape=data_train.shape)`
`fp[:] = data_train[:]`
`del fp`
`raw_input('saved! check the file & press to continue')`

the message does not get printed and pressing any keys wont do anything!

Comment: @christophTerasa: does dividing the whole dataset into two sets, and calculate mean/std for each of the set, and then adding their mean/std together, result in the same mean/std when the whole dataset is used all at once? 
Im thinking to read half of the dataset , calculate its mean/std and then save it with the next half and thus get around the memory issue. Is this correct at all ?

Comment: You can calculate the means and variances/standard deviations of the whole sample using only the means and variances/standard deviations of the subsamples. [This answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/43183) shows how to calculate the mean (at the bottom) and variance.

Comment: Thanks, I actually solved it using the very same way I asked you about and it worked.

Comment: The link I gave you actually shows that your way doesn't produce correct results. Try it with a simple example like `a = arange(10)`. Both `a[:5].std()` and `a[5:].std()` result in `1.414`, but `a.std()` is `2.872`, so the sum of both standard deviations is **not** the total standard deviation. You have to use the equations in the link. Same for the mean, you have to use the weighted mean. You can use the same example to see that `a[:5].mean() + a[5:].mean()` is `9.0`. But using the correct weight of `0.5` for both means yields the correct result of `4.5`.

Comment: oh, Thank you , you are right!, I wonder, why I got the same result then! anyway, I'll be usng the same formula from now on then. that was a very important catch!

Answer (score 1):

Why not compute the statistics on a subset of the original data? For example, here we compute the mean and std for just 100 points:

```
sample_size = 100
data_train = np.random.rand(1000, 20, 10, 10)

# Take subset of training data
idxs = np.random.choice(data_train.shape[0], sample_size)
data_train_subset = data_train[idxs]

# Compute stats
mean = np.mean(data_train_subset, axis=(0,2,3))
std = np.std(data_train_subset, axis=(0,2,3))
```

If your data is 1.7Gb, it is highly unlikely that you need all the data to get an accurate estimation of the mean and std.

In addition, could you get away with fewer bits in your datatype? I'm not sure what datatype `caffe.io.datum_to_array` returns, but you could do:

```
data = caffe.io.datum_to_array(datum).astype(np.float32)
```

to ensure the data is `float32` format. (If the data is currently `float64`, then this will save you half the space).

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately its float64, since caffe doesnt support float32 I have to use the default.
and since I need to save the normalized training set, I need to load it into ram anyway.

Comment: OK that's a shame about float32. For the normalisation though, my point is to only compute the statistics using the subset. Then you can normalise the whole dataset using these statistics. This saves you ram during the computation of `mean` and `std`, which I think is where your script is failing.

Comment: Thanks, I give a try ;)

Answer (score 0):

The culprit that caused so much issues and constant crashing due to insufficient memory, was due to batch size being the size of whole training set:

```
print 'Outputting test data'
leveldb_file = direct + 'svhn_test_leveldb_normalized'
batch_size = size_test
```

This apparently was the cause, nothing would get committed and saved to the disk until the whole dataset was read and loaded into one huge transaction, this is also the case when using `np.float32` suggested by @BillCheatham didn't work properly.

The memorymap solution wouldn't work for me for some reason and I used the solution I mentioned above.

PS: Later on, I completely changed to float32, fixed the batch_size and ran the whole thing all together, that's how I could say my former solution (divide and add the fractions together) works and gives the exact number up to 2 decimals.